Dimensionality reduction and precomputed distance matrix
I have a question about dimensionality reduction. I want to understand how methods like MDS and t-SNE work. In particular, I'd like to understand the difference when I precompute the distance matrix or not.
To try to understand it, I took 10 images from the MNIST dataset, and created 10 copies of each one of them and put them all inside one folder (in total 100 images). Then I created a distance matrix with the Modified Hausdorff Distance between all these images. Finally, I used the TSNE and MDS functions available in sklearn.manifold to project them into a 2D space. I ran both functions twice, once with the precomputed distance matrix specified (metric='precomputed') and once with the default value.
So, I have 10 images that are repeated 10 times each. I would expect to see 10 points (one per different MNIST image) composed of 10 points (10 repetitions of each image) overlapping each other in both t-SNE and MDS spaces because the distances are repeated. I only see this when I don't specify the metric as 'precomputed', not in the other case where I see dispersion.
Why is this happening? I don't know if there's any article talking about this. I would very much appreciate it if you can help me with this question.
EDIT:
Sorry for the missing information, I'm a noob on this kind of post :C
This is the heatmap of the distance matrix between the 100 images:

As you can see, it has dimensions of 100x100 with clear blocks of 10 exact same values, due to the repetition of the images.
I use that matrix, called distance_matrix, to compute the dimensionality reduction with both t-SNE and MDS. Here's the code for the t-SNE case, for both precomputed and default metrics:
# t-SNE parameters 
random_state = 10
n_iter = 50000
perplexity = 4
early_exaggeration = 1

# Apply t-SNE on the data for dimensionality reduction

# tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=random_state, n_iter = n_iter, perplexity = perplexity, early_exaggeration=early_exaggeration) 

tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=random_state, n_iter = n_iter, perplexity = perplexity, early_exaggeration=early_exaggeration, metric='precomputed', init='random')


X_tsne = tsne.fit_transform(distance_matrix)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(13,5))  
cmap = plt.get_cmap('tab10')

# Scatter plot with colors representing time progression

sc = ax1.scatter(X_tsne[:,0], X_tsne[:,1], marker='.', s=50, c=np.arange(len(X_tsne)), edgecolors='black', linewidths=0.2, cmap='rainbow')

ax1.set_xlabel('t-SNE dim 1')
ax1.set_ylabel('t-SNE dim 2')
fig.colorbar(sc, label='Time progression')

# Show the figure
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

That gives the following output:

For precomputed:

For default:


As you can see, both results are similar but not the same.

It looks "precomputed" is some specific option in the function you use. What does it stand for? What does documentation say?

According to the documentation  the metric parameter is
"The metric to use when calculating distance between instances in a feature array...If metric is “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a distance matrix."
I am using a distance matrix, that's why I don't know why is not giving the "logic" result.

Could you post the plots and possibly the code?

I believe you ought to post the distance matrix, the syntax, and the results (coordinates or the map). To make your question clear. (In particular I could not get your taking 10 "copies"...)

Sorry for the late response. I edited the post to add the code for the t-SNE, plots and distance matrix. I made an effort to provide a clearer explanation of the situation.
